# laravel confirm delete with sweetalert

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

I'm a beginner in coding php laravel please help

I use laravel 5.3 and I want to make a confirm delete by use SweetAlert

I've already install trough `"npm install"` and it's already in `node_modules` folder

the question is what I must to do next to use this modules.

Thank you

Comment: Add code to your delete button to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this;

JS Code

```
$('button#deleteButton').on('click', function(e){
var name = $(this).data('name');
e.preventDefault();
swal({
    title: "Careful!",
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete "+name+"?",
    icon: "warning",
    dangerMode: true,
    buttons: {
      cancel: "Exit",
      confirm: "Confirm",
    },
})
.then ((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
       $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
});
```

});

In view you create a button inside your form and add data-name with the name of the element being deleted;

```
<button type="submit" id="deleteButton" data-name="{{ $model->name }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
```